# Script to import csv file gives funny characters including question marks in a black diamond

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to recycle an apps script I used several months ago and am running into problems.

Within the drive directory in question there are two files:
leads_data.csv;
LeadsReport (Google Sheet).

My goal is to import data from the csv file into LeadsReport using a script.

Here is what the csv file looks like in a text editor:
[image]

So the data do appear to be separated with a comma.

Here is my apps script:

```
// add the CSV menu. Might change this to be an automatic update base don date
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Update Data", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("Update", csvMenuEntries);
}

function importFromCSV() {
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("leads_data.csv");// get the file object
      var csvFile = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();// get string content
      Logger.log(csvFile);// check in the logger
      var csvData = CSVToArray_(csvFile);// convert to 2D array
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataImport'); // only add data to the tab DataImport to prevent overwriting other parts of the spreadsheet
      sheet.getRange(2,1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);// write to sheet in one single step. Start at row 2 (getRange(2... )
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Data Updated');
    }

    function CSVToArray_(strData){
     var rows = strData.split("\r");
  // Logger.log(rows.length);
     var array = [];
      for(n=0;n<rows.length;++n){
       if(rows[n].split(',').length>1){
         array.push(rows[n].split(','));
       }
       }
    Logger.log(array);
    return array;
      
    }
```

When I save and then select the new menu item "Update" I get two unexpected outcomes:

1. "Incorrect range width, was 10 but should be 5"
2. There are two rows populated with symbols I don't recognise. The expected result was that there would be a table of data with 7 columns and ~ 3,000 rows. See picture below.
   [image]

From previous experience I tried changing between:

```
var rows = strData.split("\r");
var rows = strData.split("\n");
```

In each case I got similar results.

Can anyone see why my script is importing the data in this way?

Comment: It looks like your input file is a PDF, not a CSV text file. See the header in you sheet that appears on the first row. That explains the other error too since each row in the PDF does not necessarily have the same length and your array isn't homogeneous.

Comment: I came back after lunch and voila - it just works. I'm so confused just now. One thing I did change was this. In The directory in question there were actually 3 files: the spreadsheet with the app script, the csv file and then a Gsheets opened version of the csv file. The icon for these looked different in drive but had the exact same name. The Gsheets version existed because I opened the csv file in spreadsheets. Removing that file appears to have made all the difference. No idea why it was being read as a pdf though

Comment: Although the answer you accepted is a nice simplifying solution it won't change anything to your problem if the input file is not a text CSV file,. You still won't be able to parse it... The real solution would be to check the file content before attempting to convert it...and the answer doesn't provide anything like that. Too bad ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in csv parser. Look at the snipped below.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String)

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('CCStandards - English Language Arts & Literacy.csv').next();
  Logger.log(Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()));
}
```

// Your code adapted below

```
function importFromCSV() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("leads_data.csv");// get the file object
  var csvFile = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();// get string content
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataImport'); // only add data to the tab DataImport to prevent overwriting other parts of the spreadsheet
  sheet.getRange(2,1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);// write to sheet in one single step. Start at row 2 (getRange(2... )
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Data Updated');
}
```

Comment: Hi @Spencer. OK, but how would that integrate to the code above? I managed to put this franken script together but cutting n pasting snippets of code I found on blog posts and on SO.
I want to use the "right" method but how would the above code block look if I used parseCSV?

Comment: Check the edit above.
The change is: 
 var csvData = CSVToArray_(csvFile); 
becomes
 var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvFile);

Comment: Thanks Spencer, this also works. By saying "use the built in csv parser" it implies this is a prescribed method.
So what have I changed here? Just trying to understand. Thanks again

Comment: Interesting. I was having to write formula to remove quotes around variables in the imported data. Using parseCSV seems to have resolved this - data import with no quotes.

Comment: By 'built in' I mean a service provided in Apps Script without having to use any external libraries such as the Utilities service. 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/

Comment: I am still getting `?` even after using code in this answer.